# weak instruments stata results

Tags: regression, stata

I'm using the command ivregress 2sls, with clusters (each cluster is a school) and with pweights.

I have one endogenous variables x1, and 4 instruments. I'm trying to test my model and check if my instruments are not weak.

I used the estat firstatage command and I'm not sure how to interpret the result.
picture:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnLF8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the user-written `weakivtest` which is available from the SSC (`ssc install weakivtest`) and an improvement to `estat firststage`. If your F-test stat rejects the Null at the common significance levels (or the critical values when using `weakivtest`), your instruments are strong.